Kotlin. Android. Проблемы с переменной-классом
Я недавно начал изучать Kotlin, до этого довольно долго работал на Python. И при попытке создать свое первое приложение у меня возникла проблема. Я хотел написать вспомогательный класс для взаимодействия с API, я хотел сделать его универсальным и абстрактным, но я не могу понять, как передать класс, определенный переменной, в функцию с <>, и я не совсем уверен, что я правильно получаю класс переменной в функции, можете ли вы мне помочь?
package com.example.dndhelper.DataClasses

import android.content.Context
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
import com.beust.klaxon.Klaxon
import com.example.dndhelper.DataClasses.Spells.SpellsResponse
import org.json.JSONObject

class UrlHelper() {
    fun get(context: Context , url: String, dataClass: Any) {
        val response: String = getResponse(context, url)
        val json: JSONObject = parseSpells(response, dataClass)

}

fun getResponse(context: Context, url: String): String {
    var output: String = ""

    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
    val stringRequest = StringRequest(
        Request.Method.GET,
        url,
        {response->output = response},
        { Log.d("MyLog", "ValleyError: $it")},
    )

    queue.add(stringRequest)

    return output
}

fun parseSpells(response: String, dataClass: Any): JSONObject {
    // -------------------------------\/
    val json = Klaxon().parseArray</**?**/>(response)
    return json
}

Немного уточню вопрос еще раз. Можно ли в <> передавать класс определенный переменной, то есть записать например AbstractClass::class в переменную, и потом в другой части кода передать в <>? Я пытался сделать что-то вроде...
    fun parseSpells(response: String, dataClass: Any) {
    val json = Klaxon().parse<dataClass>(response)
}

... но это не работает

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

На Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском

Вам не надо передавать сам класс, достаточно его тип. Generics вам помогут: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html

Не понятно чего именно вы добиваетесь. parseSpells() у вас возвращает JSONObject - соответственно и Klaxon().parse() должен вернуть его же. Для чего тут generic? И, кстати, getResponse() вернёт вам пустую строку, так как запрос выполняется асинхронно - ответ нужно обрабатывать из колбека

Можно использовать типовой аргумент:
fun <T> parseSpells(response: String, dataClass: KClass<T>) {
    val json = Klaxon().parse<T>(response) 
}

